# ruby block questions loop variables

Tags: ruby, block, ruby-1.9.3

```
comics = load_comics( '/comics.txt' )

Popup.make do
  h1 "Comics on the Web"
  list do
    comics.each do |name, url|
      link name, url
    end
  end
end
```

I am new to ruby. This is a piece of code from a ruby website.

I cant find what  'link' and 'list' keyword in the menu.
can someone explain it a little bit those two keywords, and where is the definition of those two keyword .

I am also confused on how they read the variables name and url, they are reading it by the space at the same line or what?
so if I have 
Comics1 link_of_comics_site_1
Comics2 link_of_comics_site_2
Comics3 link_of_comics_site_3

so for the first iteration, name=Comics1, and url =link_of_comics_site_1

Thanks.

Comment: That code is not just Ruby.  It's using HTML generation methods from an add-on library.  What website did you get the code from?

Comment: i see. i got it right here http://tryruby.org/levels/6/challenges/6  so what does the 'list' and 'link' keyword do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not just Ruby.  That's a template for a webpage using ruby add-on methods for HTML generation.

But presumably, the result of the call to `load_comics` is a Hash, where the keys are names and the values are URLs.  You could make one of those yourself:

```
my_comics_hash = { "name1" => "url1", "name2" => "url2" }
```

which you can then iterate over the same way:

```
my_comics_hash.each do |name, url|
  puts "Name #{name} goes with URL #{url}"
end
```

In your code, it's building up an HTML list inside a popup window, but it's the same idea. The `each` method *iterates* over a collection - in this case a Hash - and runs some code on every item in that collection - in this case, each key/value pair.   When you call `each`, you pass it a block of code inside `do` ... `end`; that's the code that gets run on each item.  The current item is passed to the code block, which declares a variable to hold it inside the pipes right after the word `do`.  Since we're iterating over key/value pairs, we can declare two variables, and the key goes in the first and the value in the second.

Comment: Thankyou Mark, very helpful information. Greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In ruby function, **parenthesis** is optional and the ";" end of statement is also optional. ej

```
link "click here" , "http://myweb.com"
```

is equivalent to :

```
link("click here", "http://myweb.com");
```

But If you have more than one statement in a line the ";" is a must, ej

```
  link("click here1", "http://myweb.com"); link("click here2", "http://myweb.com");
```

In your code it could be written in

```
 link(name, url)
```

or just

```
 link(name, url);
```

or

```
 link name, url
```

But it is highly recommended to put **parenthesis** around function parameters for readability unless you have other reason . The ";" is not common in ruby world .